# Update thunderbird at ubuntu mate for gmail use

Tags: ubuntu

I can't use ThunderBird that is preinstalled in ubuntu mate for my gmail account. 
I understood that it is related to a bug that is fixed it later versions. 
When I seek updates in software center- no updates are available

What can I do?

Comment: Install from source.

Comment: I tried using apt-get, and it didn't make the update

Comment: Apt-get installs a preexisting binary, If you want a newer verion you will need to find the source code and build it for youyr Pi.

Comment: Shouldn't it be updated/ upgraded using apt-get update/ upgrade ?

Comment: As you already found out apt does not alays have the latest version. If you need a newer version you needd to compile from source. How do you expect apt to update to a verison it does not have?

Comment: Ok. I believed that it updates when a new version is released.

Comment: It takes time to get the new version into the repository (for a variety of reasons), and so the version available via apt can as you have discovered be far behind the newest version.